# Подружить Fragment и AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть необходимость унаследовать класс одновременно от Fragment и AppCompatActivity. Дело в том, что активность должна быть фрагментом, а AppCompatActivity мне нужен для того чтобы добавить к EditText всплывающие подсказки. Накнулся на проблему в самом начале.
Вот код:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Fragment,AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Вот что пишет:  'getLoaderManager()' in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' clashes with 'getLoaderManager()' in 'android.app.Activity'; attempting to use incompatible return type

Comment: Класс нельзя расширить от двух классов.

Comment: А чем обуславливается данная необходимость? Я уверен вашу проблему можно решить не нарушая правил языка

Comment: @abbath0767, вы правы, проблема уже решена, знаний по android и java минимум, а приложение уже нужно написать, оказывается наследовать класс от AppCompatActivity не нужно было, все и так работает)

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось все просто, прошу прощение за глупый вопрос)

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnFocusChangeListener{

    TextInputLayout mUsernameLayout;
    EditText mUsername;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);

        mUsernameLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.username_layout);
        mUsername = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_username);

        mUsername.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (mUsername.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            mUsernameLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
            mUsernameLayout.setError("Необходимо заполнить имя!");
        } else {
            mUsernameLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам, сначала, нужно разобраться с тем, что такое Activity и Fragment в андроид. А в данном ответе вы, просто, создали Fragment с названием SettingsActivity, т.е. судя по названию класса фрагмента, вы так и не поняли, что написали.